# Diffie Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: java, security, diffie-hellman

i am currently trying to do a diffie hellman key exchange using the java crypto libray, I have succeeded in finding a safe prime and also a generator for it. However i seem to have trouble creating a DH key with the values that i have found. It gives me the following exception

**Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DHKeyPairGenerator.java:120)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at DH.createSpecificKey(DH.java:35)
    at DH.main(DH.java:166)**

As you all know, in cryptography we cannot let our primes be small. How do i cater my safe primes and generator to fit the criteria of the DH library.

Below is my source code

```
public static void createKey()throws Exception
{
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
    kpg.initialize(512);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    KeyFactory kfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DiffieHellman");

    DHPublicKeySpec kspec = (DHPublicKeySpec) kfactory.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(), DHPublicKeySpec.class);

}

public static void createSpecificKey(BigInteger p,BigInteger g)throws Exception
{
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
    DHParameterSpec param = new DHParameterSpec(p,g);
    kpg.initialize(param);

    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

    KeyFactory kfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DiffieHellman");

    DHPublicKeySpec kspec = (DHPublicKeySpec) kfactory.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(), DHPublicKeySpec.class);

}


static boolean isPrime(long n)
{
    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 3 ; i*i<=n;i+=2)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    long pValue = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
    long gValue = randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);
    long correctPValue;

    boolean checkPrime = isPrime(pValue);
    System.out.println("the number generated is "+pValue);
    System.out.println(checkPrime);

    while(checkPrime == false)

    {
        long pValue2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
        boolean checkPrimeInLoop = isPrime(pValue2);
        //System.out.println("value in loop is "+pValue2);
        if(checkPrimeInLoop == true)
        {
            pValue=pValue2;
            break;
        }
    }


    long checkSP = (pValue*2)+1;
    boolean checkSafePrime = isPrime(checkSP);
    //System.out.println(checkSafePrime);
    while(checkSafePrime==false)
    {
        long pValue3=randomGenerator.nextInt(1000000);
        boolean checkPrimeInLoop = isPrime(pValue3);
        long pValue5=(pValue3*2)+1;
        //boolean checkSafePrimeInLoop = isPrime(pValue4);
        boolean checkSafePrime2InLoop = isPrime(pValue5);

        if(checkSafePrime2InLoop == true && checkPrimeInLoop == true)
        {
            pValue=pValue3;
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("the safe prime is"+pValue);//safe prime

    while(gValue>pValue)
    {
        long gValue2=randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);

        if(gValue2<pValue)
        {
            gValue=gValue2;
            break;
        }
    }

    long getDivisor = (pValue-1)/2;
    BigInteger bi1,bi2,bi3,bi4;

    bi1=BigInteger.valueOf(getDivisor);

    bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(pValue);

    bi3 = BigInteger.valueOf(gValue);

    bi4= bi3.modPow(bi1,bi2);

    long calculatedValue = bi4.longValue();


    while(calculatedValue == 1)
    {
        long gValue3=randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);
        long getDivisorInLoop = (pValue-1)/2;
        BigInteger bi5,bi6,bi7,bi8;

        bi5=BigInteger.valueOf(getDivisorInLoop);

        bi6 = BigInteger.valueOf(pValue);

        bi7 = BigInteger.valueOf(gValue3);

        bi8= bi7.modPow(bi5,bi6);

        long calculatedValueInLoop = bi8.longValue();
        System.out.println(calculatedValueInLoop);
        if(calculatedValueInLoop!=1)
        {
            gValue=gValue3;
            break;
        }
    }

    BigInteger generatorValue,primeValue;

    generatorValue = BigInteger.valueOf(gValue);
    primeValue = BigInteger.valueOf(pValue);

    createKey();

    int bitLength=512;

    createSpecificKey(generatorValue,primeValue);


}
```

Hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You aim to go for 512 bit length:
`kpg.initialize(512);`

You can generate p and g of such length like this:

```
int bitLength = 1024;
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, rnd);
BigInteger g = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, rnd);
```

The `probablePrime` probably use Rabin-Miller or Solovay-Strassen test which gives only 2^-100 chance (virtually no chance) that the resulting integer is not prime. Since 2002 a there's a polinomial-time algorithm called AKS (Agrawal–Kayal–Saxena) to test primes for 100% certainty (but I haven't seen it used so far, probably 2^-100 is good for anyone).

Comment: Do you have some reason that you search for specific primes in a lower range? The exception says it: "Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)"

Comment: It seems SSH (et al) use g=2 and then select a special prime for p such that q mod 12 = 5 and then 2q+1 is prime.  Something subgroup something efficient attacks using known algorithms.

So this selection of p and g probably isn't safe.

Comment: @jettero I have to read about that, but from my RSA studies I think g=2 is for speeding up computation. However since it's such a small prime, very careful attention is needed to select really good q (and p) in order to sustain the security of the scheme. That's my two cents. Nothing can be more secure than two *long* primes. The computation will be much longer though as opposed to a g=2. So I'd say maybe we should study common implementations, how they do it, probably similar way as SSH does.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is why you can only create primes from 512 to 1024 bits, while 2048 bits is recommended?! The answer is simple: the 2048 bits do not relate to the primes, but to the **size of the modulus** which is the product of the two primes. Two primes with 1024 bit each will give you a modulus of 2048 bit. That's why it's safe to use 1024 bit for the DH primes.

Regarding your exception: Csaba Toth is right: your primes are too small and the way to generate them is suboptimal. Just use your `createKey()` method and you are fine.